# Website built with Polymer don't work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, polymer

I'm building a website with polymer 1.0, but on Firefox it does not work.

By reading the console, I think the issue happens for two reasons:

1. **Every import is relative to a wrong path:**

For example, let's say my project structure is:

index.html

components

- component1.html
- component2.html

Now, if I import component1.html from component2.html (they are in the same path, so i simply use href='component2.html'), Chrome understands correctly (it imports components/component2.html), but Firefox tries to import the component2.html from root, which results in a 404 error.

2. **When an import works, and an element is imported by two or more components, on Firefox an error is throws:**

   Error: DuplicateDefinitionError: a type with name 'iron-icon' is already registered

How can i solve those issues?

Comment: maybe with this path ./component2.html ?

Comment: The issue happens even with default components (e.g. iron-icons, paper-drawer etc.), so I cannot edit the source since I use bower.

Comment: Which version of polymer ? Can you give us a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Ok... It's really weired, but refreshing the page a lot of times fixed the issue. I think that (since it isn't a vulcanized page), firefox didn't managed to download all the imported html pages. But reload after reload, all the html pages are saved in cache, and now it works.

Comment: The problem with polymer and angular templating, that they are cached so if i can give you an advice is to test your app in 'Private Browsing' (after clear your cache)